# count the rows in table before selecting only PageSize demand

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

i am trying to get the total number of rows in table `tblEmployees500k` before i am selecting num of rows by `@PageNumber`

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spPagination] -- ORDER BY EmployeeID
  @PageNumber INT,
  @PageSize   INT
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT      Emp.id ,Emp.[firstName], Emp.[lastName], Emp.[salary], Emp.[startDateWork], Emp.age, Count(1) AS [RecordCount] 
    FROM        [dbo].[tblEmployees500k]    Emp
    ORDER BY    id      
    OFFSET      @PageSize * (@PageNumber - 1) ROWS
    FETCH NEXT  @PageSize ROWS ONLY OPTION (RECOMPILE);
END
```

but `Count(1) AS [RecordCount]` causing an error

> olumn 'dbo.tblEmployees500k.id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: https://use-the-index-luke.com/no-offset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use an aggregate function you need to add non-aggregate function in `group by`.

you can try to use `Count(*) over(partition by Emp.id order by Emp.id)` to instead of `count(1)`

```
SELECT      Emp.id ,Emp.[firstName], Emp.[lastName], Emp.[salary], Emp.[startDateWork], Emp.age, Count(*) over(partition by Emp.id order by Emp.id) AS [RecordCount] 
FROM        [dbo].[tblEmployees500k]    Emp       
OFFSET      @PageSize * (@PageNumber - 1) ROWS
FETCH NEXT  @PageSize ROWS ONLY OPTION (RECOMPILE);
```

---

**EDIT**

If you want to count all rows of the table, you can try to use subquery to get total `count`

```
SELECT      Emp.id ,Emp.[firstName], Emp.[lastName], Emp.[salary], Emp.[startDateWork], Emp.age, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [dbo].[tblEmployees500k]) AS [RecordCount] 
FROM        [dbo].[tblEmployees500k]    Emp       
OFFSET      @PageSize * (@PageNumber - 1) ROWS
FETCH NEXT  @PageSize ROWS ONLY OPTION (RECOMPILE);
```

or you can use `CROSS JOIN` to make it.

```
SELECT      Emp.id ,Emp.[firstName], Emp.[lastName], Emp.[salary], Emp.[startDateWork], Emp.age,t1.cnt AS [RecordCount] 
FROM        
    [dbo].[tblEmployees500k]    Emp 
CROSS JOIN 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) cnt FROM [dbo].[tblEmployees500k]) t1      
OFFSET      @PageSize * (@PageNumber - 1) ROWS
FETCH NEXT  @PageSize ROWS ONLY OPTION (RECOMPILE);
```

Comment: when i run this query, there is another column added "RecordCount" he valure for it is always 1.. how can i count all rows of the table

Answer (score 0):

Use a window function:

```
Count(*) over () AS [RecordCount]
```

(`count(1)` and `count(*)` are equivalent.)

Comment: count(1), is more efficient, no? how can i ue this query, with mine? i tried it and it didn't work..

Comment: @E.Meir . . . They are exactly the same, unless the compile stage has some code that results in one being a cycle or two faster than the other.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `cross join` :

```
 SELECT Emp.id, Emp.[firstName], Emp.[lastName], 
        Emp.[salary], Emp.[startDateWork], Emp.age, cnt.[RecordCount]
 FROM [dbo].[tblEmployees500k] Emp CROSS JOIN
      (SELECT COUNT(*) AS [RecordCount] FROM [dbo].[tblEmployees500k]) cnt;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just declare a variable to store this info and use it in the result set like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spPagination] -- ORDER BY EmployeeID
  @PageNumber INT,
  @PageSize   INT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @NumOfRows int = (select count(*) from [dbo].[tblEmployees500k] );

SELECT      Emp.id ,Emp.[firstName], Emp.[lastName], Emp.[salary], Emp.[startDateWork], Emp.age, @NumOfRows AS [RecordCount] 
FROM        [dbo].[tblEmployees500k]    Emp
ORDER BY    id      
OFFSET      @PageSize * (@PageNumber - 1) ROWS
FETCH NEXT  @PageSize ROWS ONLY OPTION (RECOMPILE);
END
```

This way it's going to count it only once.